# Laravel 5.5 CRUD Request with Pivot

Tags: laravel, crud, query-builder

I'm trying to make a CRUD using 3 tables and a pivot table in Laravel 5.5...
- Admins (it's a user table with login system) 
- Sectors
- Langs
- lang sector

The Admin table :

```php
Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('surname');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

The Sectors table :

```php
Schema::create('sectors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

The Langs table :

```php
Schema::create('langs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('isocode', 10)->nullable();
    $table->string('langname', 80)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And the lang_sector table (pivot table):

```php
Schema::create('lang_sector', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('lang_id')->index('FK_LANGS');
    $table->integer('sector_id')->index('FK_SECTORS');
    $table->integer('admin_id')->index('FK_ADMINS');
    $table->string('sectorname', 80);
    $table->string('sectorshortname', 40)->nullable();
    $table->text('sectordescription', 65535)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->primary(['lang_id','sector_id','admin_id']);
});
```

In fact all information concerning a "sector" is stored in the pivot table ...

I also created the link in the models (admin, lang, sector) :

In lang Model :

```php
public function sectors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sector')
        ->withPivot('sectorname','sectorshortname','sectordescription', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at');
}
```

In Sector Model :

```php
public function langs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')
        ->withPivot('sectorname','sectorshortname','sectordescription', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at');
}

public function admin(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
}
```

And in Admin :

```php
public function sectors(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sector');
}
```

In order to display the data, i work with the controller and prepare my requests :

```php
public function index() {
    $langs = Lang::all();
    $admins = Admin::all();
    $sectors = DB::table('lang_sector')
        ->join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'lang_sector.lang_id')
        ->join('sectors', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
        ->join('admins', 'admins.id', '=', 'lang_sector.admin_id')
        ->select(
            'sectors.id', 'lang_sector.sector_id','lang_sector.lang_id','lang_sector.admin_id','langs.langname',
            'langs.isocode','lang_sector.sectorname','lang_sector.sectorshortname','admins.adminname','admins.adminsurname',
            'lang_sector.created_at','lang_sector.updated_at')
        ->distinct()->orderByRaw('lang_sector.sector_id')->get();

    return view('admin.sectors.sectors',compact('sectors', 'langs', 'admins'));
}
```

Technically I'm stuck with the store method...

Concerning the create method i just have to return a view :

```php
public function create()    {
    return view('admin.sectors.create');
}
```

I have doubts concernint the store method and the view...

```php
public function store(Request $request)    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'lang_id',
        'sector_id',
        'admin_id',
        'sectorname',
        'sectorshortname',
        'sectordescription',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    Sector::create($input);
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Secteur Ajouté!');
    return redirect()->route('sectors.index');
}
```

I get the Admin ID this way :

```php
<input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id}}" >
```

Ideally, I wish to create an entry for each lang at the same time ... 
or to create the relation with the main translation entry in the DB...

I'm trying to find out how to solve this but unsucessfully... 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Consider some schema changes, I did not read after I spotted `admin` table with field `adminname`, why on earth?! Just use `admin` table with `name` field etc.

Comment: i'm not sure it will have any impact on my problem ... But i'll change it in my question ...

Comment: Its just a friendly suggestion, you don't have to bother to change your question for me. Change your schema for your own sake! In future you are going to write `$admin->adminname` :face_palm:.